# what is obstacle in using google maps in iran

Tags: google-maps, dictionary

we are developing web site that one of the main functionality is map and its very important to work all the time. we want to use custom shape marker on the map. and
the site is something similar to [foursquare](https://foursquare.com/).
i want to use google map but i don't know all Obstacles in my way.
you can use it and its going to work but is it always work?
and what is my other option for map engine?
is Boycott about iran going to be problem?

Comment: try openlayers if you have a problem

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any obstacle from google for iran, but sometimes you'll see errors :D (for different reasons: network problem, ssh limitation, etc).
if your project limits to tehran you can use tehran map API else i think nothing ;)
i prefer google map now.

Comment: Also, google maps API is [freaking wonderful](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)